# Transclude does not interpolate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion, angularjs-compile, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a directive that transcludes some HTML to provide a faux context menu. The usage is as such:

```
<div id="my-element">
    My content
    <context-menu get-offset="getOffset($event)">
       <ul>
           <li>
               <a href="" ng-click="action()">{{ label }}</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </context-menu>
</div>
```

This will bind an event listener to `#my-element` which on right click will show contents of `context-menu` to whichever offset `$scope.getOffset` returns.

Everything works, except the interpolated string `{{ label }}` is not expanded. Let's say the value of `$scope.label` is `'ABC'`. Instead of seeing "ABC", you see "{{ label }}". However, ngClick seems to be bound correctly.

Please see this plunkr for the code & demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QDVAHkhrfsNpRcjTwCpM?p=preview

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The events aren't triggering a $digest cycle. Add this line to the end of `showContextMenu()`:

```
transcludeScope.$digest();
```

(You can trigger it using any scope, really)